# Where are CDE Dashboard files stored?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

For the life of me I cannot find where Pentaho stores the user-created CDE Dashboard files in the file structure?  I am using the Community Edition, and I assumed that all the files would be stored in /biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions.  When I sign into the Pentaho User Console and select Browse Files, the folders I see do not match what I see in the pentaho-solutions directory.  For example, there is a "Steel Wheels" folder in the Browse Files pane, but I cannot find it in the Pentaho directory.  Similarly, if I create a folder and a CDE Dashboard within it, I cannot find it in the Pentaho directory.  I have done find / -name "*.wcdf" and it doesn't find the CDE Dashboard I created.

I have tried a couple tutorials where I manually create the CDF files, such as index.properties, index.xml, the .xcdf file and .html file, and if I place the files in a folder in the /biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions directory (and of course, stop and start the Pentaho server), I do not see the dashboard show up in the Browse Files pane through the Pentaho User Console.

The files must be somewhere; likewise, if we manually create the files per the tutorials, they must be able to be placed somewhere for the PUC to pick them up.  Can anyone please help?  Sadly, I have already spent hours on this and not sure I will be able to figure this out without some help.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it depends on Pentaho version. From Pentaho 5 till current Pentaho 7 the Jackrabbit JCR repository is used to sort of 'emulate' a file system, but with possibilities to store the entire system in different storage types. Most of Pentaho server objects, such as CDF dashboards, datasource definitions etc are stored in this repository. In the default pentaho installation JCR uses a database with name 'jackrabbit' in your DBMS to persist its state. But the actual repository location can be defined somewhere in configuration files in `pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot directly access the dashboard files outside the pentaho
>   server. If you want to access these files outside then you need to
>   download these files, you can download
>   dashboard.wcdf,dashboard.cda,dashboard.cdfde files from Pentaho your
>   console. Then again if you want to send your dashboard to your friend
>   or someone you can upload these files in pentaho user console.